# Does g++ not take header files from the first include path it exists in?

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to build a [third party tool](https://github.com/l0b0/dcp2icc). I'm not very familiar with the C++ build tools, and I'm not sure how this should be resolved.

`dcp2icc.src/dcp2icc.cpp` line 6 is:

```
#include "dng_camera_profile.h"
```

`dng_sdk_1_2/dng_sdk/source/dng_camera_profile.h` line 39:

```
#include "dng_hue_sat_map.h"
```

There are *two* `dng_hue_sat_map.h` files:

```
$ ls -l dng_sdk_1_2/dng_sdk/source/dng_hue_sat_map.h fixes/dng_sdk/dng_hue_sat_map.h
-r--r--r-- 1 user users 3141 Apr  9  2008 dng_sdk_1_2/dng_sdk/source/dng_hue_sat_map.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 3124 Oct 31  2015 fixes/dng_sdk/dng_hue_sat_map.h
```

Finally, this is the command which gets run:

```
g++ -o build/dcp2icc/dcp2icc.o -c -m32 -O2 -iquote- -DUNIX_ENV=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DkBigEndianHost=0 -Idcp2icc.src -Ifixes/dng_sdk -Idng_sdk_1_2/dng_sdk/source -INone dcp2icc.src/dcp2icc.cpp
```

I expected that because `-Ifixes/dng_sdk` comes before `-Idng_sdk_1_2/dng_sdk/source`, `fixes/dng_sdk/dng_hue_sat_map.h` would be used, but this is not the case:

```
In file included from dng_sdk_1_2/dng_sdk/source/dng_camera_profile.h:39:0,
                 from dcp2icc.src/dcp2icc.cpp:6:
dng_sdk_1_2/dng_sdk/source/dng_hue_sat_map.h:129:8: error: extra qualification 'dng_hue_sat_map::' on member 'operator==' [-fpermissive]
   bool dng_hue_sat_map::operator== (const dng_hue_sat_map &rhs) const;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How does g++ choose which file to use when the header file exists in two include locations? Does it matter which sequence the `include`s are in, and if so, how?

`man g++` simply has this to say:

> -I dir
>
> Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files.  Directories named by -I are searched before the standard system include directories.  If the directory dir is a standard system include            directory, the option is ignored to ensure that the default search order for system directories and the special treatment of system headers are not defeated .  If dir begins with "=", then the "=" will be replaced by the            sysroot prefix; see --sysroot and -isysroot.

The [GCC spec](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) says the following, which as far as I can tell is the opposite of what I'm seeing:

> You can specify multiple -I options on the command line, in which case the directories are searched in left-to-right order.

Comment: That's the spec for GCC, and is in my experience what happens. You must have other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `#include "..."` form, rather than the `#include <...>` form.

The file `dng_sdk_1_2/dng_sdk/source/dng_camera_profile.h` is including `"dng_hue_sat_map.h"`. `#include "..."` first searches relative to the file doing the including, so it first searches in `dng_sdk_1_2/dng_sdk/source`, regardless of `-I` options.

Comment: Ah. What would be the recommended fix, since I can't change the original code? Just overwrite it with the replacement file?

Comment: @l0b0 I think my approach would be to place a copy of `dng_camera_profile.h` in the `fixes/dng_sdk` directory (or a symlink). That would make `#include "dng_camera_profile.h"` pick up that version, which would in turn pick up `"dng_hue_sat_map.h"` from there as well.